# Is there an alternate way to run a scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy

The following code takes a url, crawls it for all the links in it then validates those links.

```
runner = CrawlerRunner()
list = set([])
list_validate = set([])
list_final = set([])    


class Crawler(CrawlSpider):

name = "Spider"
start_urls = ['https://example.com']
allowed_domains = ['example.com']
rules = [Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_links', follow=True)]
configure_logging({'LOG_FORMAT': '%(levelname)s: %(message)s'})

def parse_links(self, response):
    base_url = url
    href = response.xpath('//a/@href').getall()
    list.add(urllib.parse.quote(response.url, safe=':/'))
    for link in href:
        if base_url not in link:
            list.add(urllib.parse.quote(response.urljoin(link), safe=':/'))
    for link in list:
        if base_url in link:
            list_validate.add(link)

def run_spider():
   d = runner.crawl(Crawler)

   def validate(d):
        for link in list_validate:
        error = http.request("GET", link)
        if error.status == 200:
            list_final.add(link)

        for link in list_final:
            print(link)

   d.addCallback(validate)
   reactor.run(0)
```

I was wondering if there is another way of writing the `run_spider()` function. I want to know if it is possible to achieve the same result without `addCallback(validate)`. So to recap, I want to run the spider, then add links to a list, and then validate that list. The validate function has to run after the spider is complete in order to validate the links that got added to the list. So is there a way to achieve this result but with different code?

Comment: Have you looked at Item Pipelines? https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html

Comment: I was hoping to find a way to change the function itself

Answer (score 0):

You can [use coroutines sytanx](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/defer-intro.html#coroutines-with-async-await) with Twisted deferreds.